# Get some sort of Top Ten list of one column from table

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics

I'd like to get some sort of Top Ten list from a table a MySQL database. 
Here's an example. Let's say I have this table:

```
ID  Username    Town
 1  foo         Munich
 2  bar         Kolding
 3  herp        Bordeaux
 4  derp        Bordeaux
 5  test        Cologne
 6  bla         Munich
 7  blob        Bordeaux
```

And now, I'd like to get the most common entries in 'Town', like this:

```
Bordeaux  3
Munich    2
Cologne   1
Kolding   1
```

What kind of query can do that?

Comment: Weeeee, look at all the downvotes. I love you too.

Comment: It's because you're not showing any research effort (i.e., this is basic sql)

Comment: @Keyser: `GROUP BY` is not *that* basic.

Comment: @eggyal It's not the first thing you learn, but it's definitely part of the basic training :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this.

```
SELECT Town, Count(1) as TownCount 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY Town
ORDER BY TownCount DESC;
```

If you want only 10 records, use

```
SELECT Town, Count(1) as TownCount 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY Town
ORDER BY TownCount DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Town, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM my_table GROUP BY Town ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT town,
       count(*)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY town;
```